# Is a decreasing sequence of functions which is bounded below necessarily convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I know that it's true that a decreasing sequence of real numbers which is bounded below is convergent, but is the same true of sequences of functions?

That is, for a sequence $\{f_n\}$ on a domain $A$ such that $f_n \geq f_{n+1}$, if the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is bounded below, is it necessarily true that there exists a function $f$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$ (i.e., is $\{f_n\}$ pointwise convergent on $A$)?

This might be obvious or well-known, but admittedly analysis is not my forte.

Comment: Depends - there are a lot of different definitions of function convergence, and which space of cunctions you are in. But pointwise convergence is clearly true by the result from the reals.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence of functions to converge in this case?

Comment: There are various modes of convergence of function sequences, so...?

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of my original post; it's been updated.  @ThomasAndrews , I suspected this was the case, but I'm always a little afraid to trust my intuition when it comes to analysis!  I realize though that, in general, uniform convergence is a bit too much to ask for.